# Has Nambu's notion of an "eigenoperator" found a place in the mathematical literature?

Tags: matrices, oa.operator-algebras, eigenvalues, differential-operators

The physicist [Yoichiro Nambu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoichiro_Nambu) introduced in a 1950 paper [A Note on the Eigenvalue Problem in Crystal Statistics](http://www.totoha.net/archiv/3675.pdf) the notion of an "*eigenoperator*" (page 12, see [Nambu and the Ising model](https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.01122) for a recent discussion of this early work by the 2008 Nobel laureate).

Given a self-adjoint operator $H$, the eigenoperator $X$ satisfies
$$HX-XH=\lambda X,\;\;\lambda\in\mathbb{R}.$$

**Q:** A Google search for "eigenoperator" does not return much, has this notion found its place in the mathematical literature, perhaps under a different name?

---

I append a screenshot of the relevant paragraph from Nambu's paper:

[image]

Footnote 6) refers  to Nambu's paper [On the Method of the Third Quantization](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/On-the-Method-of-the-Third-Quantization.-Nambu/6f3f8b38cf6c6963627cfc883afc580d347b4e95), where $X$ is called an "eigenmatrix".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Such an $X$ is an *eigenvector of $\,\operatorname{ad}(H)$*. Joint eigenspace decompositions of several $\operatorname{ad}(H_i)$ are commonplace in math since the work of Lie, Killing, Cartan, with the joint eigenvectors called *root vectors*. So I would say that the notion “had a place” already before Nambu.

Comment: Indeed, although probably not as easily describable before the gradual acceptance of a more abstract style post-Bourbaki...?  .... including various levels of "(mathematical) reification" (=making an operation on things a thing in itself, that perhaps could be operated upon...)

Comment: @paulgarrett You are right that one may perhaps not find $\text{ad}(\cdot)$ before Chevalley and Eilenberg [[1941](//mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=4632), [1948](//mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=24908)], nor *root vector* before Wang and Dynkin [[1949](//mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=32658), [1952a](//mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=49903), [1952b](//mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=47629)].